# Yii2 Access Rules Using Different Models

Tags: yii2, access-rules, role-based-access-control, yii2-model

I'm having trouble with Yii2 Role Based Access Control. In the usual set-up, the authentication rule takes place when the identity of the current user. Like written in the docs. [Authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#using-rules)

In my case, how can I set up the authorization (aside from the basic feature) using another set of models.? Here is my set up.

Table `auth_assignment` [`item_name`, `user_id`] from rbac migration, 
`user` [`id`] from the yii2 migration.
I created a new table `assignment` [`user_id` related to `user`, `rec_id` related to `recognition` of an `organization`].

This is the scenario. I have the roles `admin`, `organization-head`, `member`. How can I check if the `organization-head`, or `member` belongs to their own Recognition module; not the other modules from other organization-heads?

I used also the context access control filter by [peixoto](http://programming.peixoto.cf/2015/01/14/yii2-role-based-access-control-and-context-access-rule/).

Here is my code for checking. RecognitionRule checks if there is a user `user_id` equal to the identity of the user; and `account_id` equal to `rec_id`. The second condition tells if he is belong to the organization

```
/**
 * Checks if ID matches user passed via params
 */
class RecognitionRule extends Rule
{
    public $name = 'isRecognition';

    /**
     * @param string|integer $user the user ID.
     * @param Item $item the role or permission that this rule is associated with
     * @param array $params parameters passed to ManagerInterface::checkAccess().
     * @return boolean a value indicating whether the rule permits the role or permission it is associated with.
     */
    public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        if(isset($params['recognition'])){ //Directly specify the model you plan to use via param
            $model = $params['recognition']; 
        }else{ //Use the controller findModel method to get the model - this is what executes via the behaviour/rules
            $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id'); //Note, this is an assumption on your url structure. 
            $model = Yii::$app->controller->findModel($id); //Note, this only works if you change findModel to be a public function within the controller.
        }
        return \common\models\Assignment::find()->where(['rec_id' => $model->id, 'user_id' => $user])->exists();
    }
}
```

Still, I am not allowed to perform the action. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answers. I based my answer on [AccessRule behavior and rbac\Rule $params](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4302)

snippet of the RecognitionRule

```
/**
 * @param string|integer $user the user ID.
 * @param Item $item the role or permission that this rule is associated with
 * @param array $params parameters passed to ManagerInterface::checkAccess().
 * @return boolean a value indicating whether the rule permits the role or permission it is associated with.
 */
public function execute($user, $item, $params)
{
    if(isset($params['recognition'])){ //Directly specify the model you plan to use via param
        $model = $params['recognition']; 
    } else{ //Use the controller findModel method to get the model - this is what executes via the behaviour/rules
        $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id'); //Note, this is an assumption on your url structure.
    }

    return \common\models\Assignment::find()->where(['rec_id' => $id, 'user_id' => $user])->exists();
}
}
?>
```

RecognitionController

```
                [
                    'class' => 'common\rbac\ContextAccessRule',
                    'modelClass' => 'frontend\models\recognition',
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['view','update'],
                    'roles' => ['viewOwnRecognition', 'updateOwnRecognition'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
```